# I can't create new project in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, project, lowcode

I am new to WordPress. And I can not find the project section from where I can manage multiple projects. But currently, I am just stuck with this project and can not create other projects simultaneously. And there is a difference in the dashboard of others on the internet.

[My WordPress Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQmp6.png)

support help (internet source)
[Other's WordPress dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89T8p.png)

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, just the dashboard you want is being modified by some plugin. This means that you currently have a clean version of wordpress, without any plugins, and the dashboard you want is the result of installing some plugin. In this case it is a **WP Data Access plugin**. I think after you install this plugin you will get what you want :)

Link to this plugin: [Click here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-data-access/)